# Add values of two different php arrays

Tags: php, arrays

My question is about how to add the values from two different arrays, that each have 20 records.

**$array1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => mysqli_result Object
        (
            [current_field] => 0
            [field_count] => 1
            [lengths] => 
            [num_rows] => 220
            [type] => 0
        )


    [1] => mysqli_result Object
        (
            [current_field] => 0
            [field_count] => 1
            [lengths] => 
            [num_rows] => 70
            [type] => 0
        )
```

**$array2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => mysqli_result Object
        (
            [current_field] => 0
            [field_count] => 1
            [lengths] => 
            [num_rows] => 280
            [type] => 0
        )

[1] => mysqli_result Object
        (
            [current_field] => 0
            [field_count] => 1
            [lengths] => 
            [num_rows] => 30
            [type] => 0
        )
```

I would like to get a third array like that (adding the values of $array1 and $array2):

```
Array
(
    [0] => mysqli_result Object
        (
            [current_field] => 0
            [field_count] => 1
            [lengths] => 
            [num_rows] => 500
            [type] => 0
        )

[1] => mysqli_result Object
        (
            [current_field] => 0
            [field_count] => 1
            [lengths] => 
            [num_rows] => 100
            [type] => 0
        )
```

How do I do this? All operations I've tried only added the values one after another (new array with 40 rows), not adding them.

**EDIT SOLUTION**

```
$array3 = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array2); $i++) {
array_push($array3, $array1[$i]->num_rows + $array2[$i]->num_rows); 
}
```

Comment: Looks like your trying to add the count of rows in two SQL queries.

Comment: 70 + 30 = 100 not 1000

Comment: Better to do this in MySQL than PHP

Comment: This is XY problem. Somewhere else something is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to do that could be using a for loop and use the index of the arrays to add the num_rows of `$array1` to `$array2`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    $array2[$i]->num_rows += $array1[$i]->num_rows;
}
```

Comment: this way the values stayed the same

Comment: @Lama222 Did you run a `print_r($array2);` For example lik https://3v4l.org/J8LJd

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add every single value of an array($array1) to another array($array3) you need to take a foreach like this :

```
foreach($array1 as $array) {
    $array3[] = $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$resultArray = array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

Comment: this way the values of the second array add to the first, giving 40 records instead of 20, and the values are not additioned